# Error running meteor in MAC

Tags: macos, meteor

I am trying to run meteor app on MAC without success with following error. Surprisingly other project is running properly in MAC and very this project runs properly on Windows. But in MAC I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
/Users/user1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xh5uo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Must throw non-empty error
    at Object.Future.throw (/Users/user1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xh5uo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:259:10)
    at /Users/user1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xh5uo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:541:23
    at runWithEnvironment (/Users/user1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xh5uo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:139:21)
    at /Users/user1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xh5uo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:146:14
    at /Users/user1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xh5uo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:549:11
```

Comment: I've had the same problem on linux machine. Not sure why, but switching to `0.12.4` version of node, running project (and getting error) and then back to latest stable `0.12.7` version solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably related problems fetching the packages, see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4921